# HTML <select> element is not rendering in ReactJS Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to react and these days i'm facing a huge issue.
When i create some components, those are not rendering in the main class when i add it. As an example, please check this code.

This is my Planet.js class where I added Select element.
https://gist.github.com/chanakaDe/d839c1e20e7ae018c2d6ea8669646da1
Here I added a normal select element and also a select loading from dynamic data. Both are not appearing. But the HTML button is there and it's appearing.

This is my App.js class and this is where i import Planet.js.
https://gist.github.com/chanakaDe/1ffd9cdc33347d6c77251bee495be1c3#file-app-js-L47

You can see it in line no 47. HTML text and also HTML button us rendering. But not even the hard coded select element is loading. Please can anyone tell me why is this?

Comment: It's rendering fine on my Machine.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcmk3pzv2nb60fi/Screenshot%202018-04-23_12-04-45.png?dl=0
Do you have any errors in your terminal or browser devTools?

Comment: I assume, it's not ReactJS issue. Here is your example in the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/l7nmk8mw69. So, as told @konekoya, share your errors from console if you have it.

Comment: Where is you handler method when selecting any values or option